# Easier version of "Problem Solving Strategies" by Engel?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I am preparing to take the Putnam next year. Currently I own the book in the title, but the material might be a little too difficult for me. I have gone through the first eight examples in the first section; I tried to solve each one but couldn't, and it also took me a long time to understand the solution once I read it.

Is there a book that is slightly easier than Engel's? I thought of looking at books for highschool competitions, but I don't think learning to solve those types of problems is very useful; many of them seem to rely much more heavily on memorized tricks (such as special factorizations and algebraic manipulations).

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Someone recommended George Polya's book "How to Solve It", but unfortunately that person deleted their comment. Is this a good book for my level? I happen to have a copy but I never went through it.

Comment: Where are you planning to take the exam? There are often practice sessions by the math department.

Comment: @martycohen I am currently taking a seminar (in whcih I am the only student) at my university. However, it doesn't really have any structure; the professor just solves 1-2 problems on the board once a week for 50 minutes. Of course I need to be the one putting in 99% of the work, but I've been extremely busy and devoted only about 2 hours a week to that class. Now I have time and I am planning to study as much as I can for this year's Putnam,  but I am more looking forward to next year's. I can solve some of the easier ones sometimes, I'd honestly be very happy to solve just one on the exam

Comment: From Spain there exists a reference (I don't know if is a more easier version than yours), the *model of problem solving* due to **Miguel de Guzmán** (was a professor and great specialist in analysis), but I can not find references  explaining the method, strategies and main ideas in english language that you can read.

Comment: Try "Art of Problem Solving Vol 2" and may be Polya's "How to solve it".